# Writing JSON to an output file using tool sstable2json in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to export the SSTables to JSON. So I am using `sstable2json.bat`. I am able to run this bat using command prompt and can see the JSON result printing on command prompt itself. I used the following command:

```
sstable2json H:/cassandra/db/data/191/191/191-191-hd-1-Data.db
```

I have to write this JSON content to an output file. For that I used the following command:

```
sstable2json -f H:/output.json H:/cassandra/db/data/191/191/191-191-hd-1-Data.db
```

But this command is showing me exception like:

```
You must supply exactly one sstable
Usage: org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport
<sstable> [-k key [-k key [...]]
-x key [-x key [...]]]
```

Can any one correct my mistake if any. I am using Cassandra 1.1.2 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redirect stdout to a file.  You can find the documentation for redirection here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

For example:

```
 sstable2json H:/cassandra/db/data/191/191/191-191-hd-1-Data.db>mysstable.json
```

The contents will then be in a file named `mysstable.json`.

Comment: ...Your solution is working fine for me... Then I explored API in SSTableExport.java from Cassandra... It does not has option to handle the file writer as mentioned in here:http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Import_.2BAC8_export... Have I referred correctly?...

Comment: Looks like the wiki was either wrong or out of date. I've updated it, thanks.

Comment: @Tyler Hobbs.. Is it possible to export entire column family using command "sstable2json H:/cassandra/db/data/191/191>mysstable.json"..If not possible to how to export column family without having to define the  191-191-hd-1-Data.db?